# Refit - ApiResponse<T> wrapping in a methods cannot get access to content

Tags: c#, refit

I am using refit and works great but I am also new to it.

I have the need to wrap up ApiResponse in a call (see below) because within this method I will do things like

- Logging
- Handling exceptions
- etc..
  but I cannot make it work as its null!!

Caller

```
   var response = await ExecuteAsync(() => webApiClient.GetStuff());
```

Method where apiresponse is null

```
public async Task<T> ExecAsync<T>(
        Func<Task<T>> method) where T : class
    {
       T apiResponse = await method.Invoke();
        ApiResponse<T> apiResponseOfT =apiResponse as ApiResponse<T>;//this is null
        if (apiResponseOfT.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //do other stuff
            return apiResponse;
        }
        else
        {
            //do some logging etc..
            return apiResponse;
        }
    }
```

What Am I doing wrong - Why is it null?
Is it possible to return just the apiResponse.Content?

How do I wrap up ApiResponse in an ExecAsync?

Updated

See below to give more context ...

```
    [Get("/api/v1/customers")]
    Task<ApiResponse<GetCustomerResponse>> GetCustomers();
    
    public class GetCustomerResponse:ResponseBase
    {
        //various properties here...
    }
     public abstract class ResponseBase
    {
          public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    ApiResponse<GetCustomerResponse> response = await ExecuteAsync(() => webApiClient.GetCustomers())
```

Comment: I'm very confused what you are asking - you know that you need `Func<Task<ApiResponse<T>>> method` but somehow don't like it... Any *specific* criteria of "like" so the question can be answered?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hi thanks for your reply I have edited the question to avoid confusion. What I am doing wrong in that ExecAsync?

Comment: `T` is pretty much never `ApiResponse<T>` (and I'm 100% sure that refit can even do  `T : ApiResponse<T>` as `T` is provided to it from outside). You really want to replace `var` with explicit types to see what is going on.

Comment: Cannot be used as parameter constraint as its sealed. I have edited the question with explicity types.

Comment: Can you show sample interface that you feed to refit? It should be something like ` ApiResponse<int> GetNumber()` to be able to use ApiResponse...

Comment: I have updated the question -hope it makes sense

Comment: I see where I got confused - I assumed `T` is response type (like "customer"), but you just pass  method to your helper ending up with `T` being `ApiResponse<TResponse>`... Tia's answer indeed what you need (and I thought that it is what you did not like...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the declaration to `public async Task<ApiResponse<T>> ExecAsync<T>(Func<Task<ApiResponse<T>>> method) where T : class` and changing the implementation accordingly should do. Something like

```
public async Task<ApiResponse<T>> ExecAsync<T>(
    Func<Task<ApiResponse<T>>> method) where T : class
{
    var apiResponseOfT = await method();
    if (apiResponseOfT.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //do other stuff
        return apiResponse;
    }
    else
    {
        //do some logging etc..
        return apiResponse;
    }
}
```

If you are not planning to throw any exception, you can just return after if-else instead.

Comment: That worked - excellent and thank you for your time. So simple when I see it and yet I struggled.. thank you